# Advanced mail filtering on mail.app

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

So I have been trying this for weeks but am not able to make it work optimally. Here are some screenshots of my settings:[image: Here are some screenshots of my settings] and the mail filter rules:[image: the mail filter rules] I want to apply mail filtering for specific cases such as the mail should filter everything from gitlab as junk but not those emails that have a specific keyword in the header like the name of a repo. How can I apply such rules.

I have tried changing *If **any** of the following conditions are met* to *If **all** of the following conditions are met* but that seems logically incorrect and here are the set of rules that I applied

- from ends with gitlab@mg.gitlab.com
- subject does not contain *keyword*

but it still filters everything from gitlab

Comment: You included the gmail tag, so I'm assuming you use gmail? Why aren't you just using their web interface to filter mail?

Comment: @JBallin I am not sure if I have ever heard of the web interface but I decided to use rules instead of this web filtering thing on Mac mail and now my each and every mail goes to junk.

Comment: @JBallin yes I am using gmail. Can you provide me the link?

Comment: Web Gmail: gmail.com